# I want to write my product name like this - my_productnam....more... | in django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, e-commerce, slice

```
<div class="itemCard_Name">{{i.Title |slice:"0:30"}}...</div>
```

If Name of item crosses the limit of max characters then "More..." button should be automatically placed at 31st character.

Answer (score 0):

TRY:

```
{{ i.Title|slice:":30" }} {% if i.Title|length > 30 %}<button type="button">More...</button>{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what custom template filter does:

[custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-template-tags/)